# Xamarin.Forms Page BackgroundImage property

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How are you supposed to set the background image for a Page, as the BackgroundImage is a string? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

So far I've tried:

```
MainPage = new ContentPage 
{
    BackgroundImage = "Images/image.png"
}
```

which does not work. The image file is located in the PCL project.

Comment: The images must be in Platform specific folders, e.g `Resources/drawable ` for android and `Resources` for iOS

Comment: I added the image to the `Resources/drawable` folder (now testing on Android), but it still does not work...

Comment: I already did that

Comment: Whats your device resolution? If its of higher resolution then add image to each drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi,

Comment: It's working, I was looking at the device from an angle and the background was dark so I didn't notice it, lol, so thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you can't share resources. you must put the image in Platform Specific folder and than use `BackgroundImage = "image.png"` without `Images/`

**EDIT:**

It seems I was partly mistaken.

It is possible to share images by embedding them instead of having multiple copies for different Platforms: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images

Comment: I'd like to suggest to add PCL for resources and then add links to files (**As Link**) to platform specific folders as you suggested.

Comment: You most certainly can share resources (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images)

Comment: well, I guess I didn't remember it correctly. thanks.

Comment: I didn't knew about it either. Thanks for sharing.@misho

Answer (score 14):

If you need a solution that allows you to change the **AspectRatio** and adjust the image you can use this:

XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Pages.PhotoPage">
        <Grid >
            <Image Source="background.png" Aspect="AspectFit" />
            <!-- Place here the rest of the layout for the page. -->
        </Grid >
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the image on a page:

```
<Image Source="bg"></Image>
```

Now you need to add your image on each platform:

iOS

```
Test.iOS > Resources > bg.png
```

Android

```
Test.Droid > Resources > bg.png
```