# Set Background Image Aspect in Code Behind in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms 5 app, I set a background image in code behind using the following code:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
   public MyPage()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.BackgroundImageSource = "my_bg_image.jpg";
   }
}
```

How do I set the image aspect ratio in ***code behind***? I need to set it to `AspectFill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ToolmakerSteve mentioned, there's no way to set `Aspect` for `BackgroundImageSource`. The following code works fine, both in terms of setting the background image correctly and handling the keyboard covering the form elements issue on iOS.

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <Image
      Source="my_background_image.jpg"
      Aspect="AspectFill"
      RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
      RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>
   <ScrollView
      Orientation="Neither"
      Padding="0"
      RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
      RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">
   // Place my form elements here. In my case, I use Grid
   </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set **any** property of any element in your xaml, by giving that element an `x:Name`.

```xml
<Image x:Name="myImage" ... />
```

c#:

```cs
myImage.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill;
```

Comment: This doesn't really work for `BackgroundImageSource` though. As mentioned in the original post, I'm trying to set a background image for my login page. Whether I set the `BackgroundImageSource` in XAML or code behind, I can't seem to set the `Aspect` for the image. To make it more challenging, I have the usual username/password entries on the login page which require me to use a `ScrollView` so that on iOS, I can prevent the soft keyboard from covering up my controls. I've found some solutions using `AbsoluteLayout` or `RelativeLayout` but I'm a bit afraid to use them due to keyboard concerns.

Comment: ok. I’ve never heard of a BackgroundImageSource property, so I did not realize what you were doing. Can’t set aspect of page’s BackgroundImage. So you’ll have to fake it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37879628/199364. That’s a single cell grid, with an image behind another layout, containing the rest of your content.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I mustered enough courage to try `RelativeLayout` and it seems to do the trick. Thanks again!